# drop_all() freezes in Flask with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask

I am writing test cases for a Flask application.

I have a setUp method which drops the tables in the db before re-creating them again. 
It looks like this:

```
def setUp(self):
    # other stuff...
    myapp.db.drop_all()
    myapp.db.create_all()
    # db creation...
```

This works fine for the first test, but it freezes at `drop_all` before the second test is run.

**EDIT:** 
The stack trace looks like this when interrupting the process

```
  File "populate.py", line 70, in create_test_db
    print (myapp.db.drop_all())
  File ".../flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 864, in drop_all
    self._execute_for_all_tables(app, bind, 'drop_all')
  File ".../flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 848, in _execute_for_all_tables
    op(bind=self.get_engine(app, bind), tables=tables)
  File ".../sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 3335, in drop_all
  ....
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 190, in execute
    r = self._query(query)
```

Anybody has a clue how to fix this?

Answer (score 45):

Oki, there might be other solutions but for now, after searching the interwebs, I found that the problem disappears if I prepend my code with a `myapp.db.session.commit()`. I guess, somewhere a transaction was waiting to be committed.

```
def setUp(self):
    # other stuff...
    myapp.db.session.commit()   #<--- solution!
    myapp.db.drop_all()
    myapp.db.create_all()
    # db creation...
```

Comment: Same issue was with postgres.

Comment: Including more context about what actually went wrong in the database flow would be great. This answer here kinda just tells people that commit is a "solution" but there's no details about the problem stated.

Answer (score 30):

Just close all sessions in your app and after that invoke `drop_all`

```
    def __init__(self, conn_str):
        self.engine = create_engine(conn_str)
        self.session_factory = sessionmaker(engine)
        
    def drop_all(self):
        self.session_factory.close_all() # <- don't forget to close
        Base.metadata.drop_all(self._engine)
```

more information about Sessions in SQLAlchemy
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html?highlight=close_all

Comment: What an amazing, incredible, wonderful, lovely, beautiful person you are. Thank you so much.

Comment: Had this same issue with SQLAlchemy in Pyramid. Thanks!

Comment: Note that for SQLAlchemy 1.3 "the Session.close_all() method is deprecated and will be removed in a future release." The new command is: `from sqlalchemy.orm.session import close_all_sessions` then `close_all_sessions()`.

Answer (score 5):

I am a Flask developer and using flask_sqlalchemy and pytest to test my app server, I run into similar situation when I run the statement `db.drop_all()`, console shows that one of my table is locked.

I use `db.session.remove()`to remove the session before running db.drop_all().

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, in my case I had 2 different sessions making queries to the same table. My solution was to use one scoped_session for both places.

I created it in a different module so I had no problem with circular dependencies, like this:

db.py:

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()
```

models.py:

```
from .db import db
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
```

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from .db import db
app = Flask(__name__)
db.init_app(app)
```

Using only the `db.session` in all your code will guarantee that you are in the same session. In the tests, make sure you execute the rollback at tearDown.