# How to clear the MySQL database from pytest fixture

Tags: python, python-3.x, tdd, flask-sqlalchemy, pytest

I am creating an **API** using **Python Flask**. I am trying to apply TDD (Test Driven Development) for the development.

But whenever I am using the **db.drop_all()** from **pytest** **fixture** and running the test from the terminal it freezes at the time of exiting from the test.

Sharing the code via Gist - https://gist.github.com/himadriganguly/9a431fd329897c9e9e3fb6113ff5eae1

Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should try forcing a session commit, as you probably have incomplete transactions:

```
db.session.commit()
db.clear_all()
```

Check out "[drop_all() freezes in Flask with SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24289808/drop-all-freezes-in-flask-with-sqlalchemy)", there are people there also suggesting to close all sessions, so you should try that as well.