# Deprecated Session.close_all() vs 'scoped_session' object has no attribute 'close_all_sessions'

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy

I am trying to use 'drop_all' after service test fails or finishes on flask app layer:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def db_connection():
    db_url = TestConfig.db_url
    db = SQLAlchemyORM(db_url)
    db.create_all(True)
    yield db_connection
    db.drop_all()
```

When some test passes the 'drop_all' works, but when it fails the test freezes.

So, that solution solves my problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44437760/3050042

Unfortunately, I got a mess with that.

When I use the 'Session.close_all()' SQLAlchemy warns:

```
The Session.close_all() method is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.  Please refer to session.close_all_sessions().
```

When I change to the suggestion:

```
AttributeError: 'scoped_session' object has no attribute 'close_all_sessions'
```

Yes, I use scoped_session and pure SQLAlchemy.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `close_all_sessions` function is defined at the top level of `sqlalchemy.orm.session`. At the time of writing this answer, [here](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/96dba1a9f4bdbce43159c5b3741e7626ddd21d47/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py#L3939) is how it looks. Thus, you can use it as follows.

```
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import close_all_sessions


close_all_sessions()
```

Answer (score 0):

asyncio (AsyncSession) analog:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import close_all_sessions

await close_all_sessions()
```